# Prometheus query to alert if something happens x times within a time period?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm working on a query that should alert if the disk queue length gets above 2 frequently. Say, if it happens 10 times over a 1d period.

I can't seem to get my head around this one. I would first need the amount of times the issue occurs, so:
`count(windows_logical_disk_requests_queued > 2)`

Then I'd need to check how many times this query occurred over the last 1d. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [count_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time). Something like:
`count_over_time(windows_logical_disk_requests_queued[1d]) > 10`

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

I tried this but it gives this error:
`Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:17: parse error: binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types`

Comment: Sorry, there was a wrong parenthesis. I validated in my local prometheus and it should work. I update the answer.